# How to get GitHub repo latest release in Python?

Tags: python, github, web-scraping

**What i'm looking for**

I am working on a project that has a repo on GitHub, and I was wondering, is there a way to retrieve the latest release on GitHub in Python?

**What I tried**

I looked for a sort of `details.json` on the GitHub repo website so I can convert the file into a python dictionary. I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) makes this pretty straightforward. For example,

```py
from github import Github

token = None # Put your GitHub API token here if you want to access a private repo.
repo_path = "PyGithub/PyGithub"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Github(token)
    repo = g.get_repo(repo_path)
    latest = repo.get_latest_release()
    print(latest.title) # Prints v1.58.1 as of this writing.
```

Comment: Thank you! What is an API token, though? How can I create one? And also, by putting my token in my public code, is that dangerous?

Comment: @BitPigeon You definitely should not share your API token with anyone. If the repo is public, though, I think you can get away with not providing a token; I've updated my answer to reflect that. If you need a GitHub API token, you can follow [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).